# curl_setopt_array for USPTO records returns "Internal Sever Error1"

Tags: php, php-curl

I'm trying to test retrieving an USPTO dataset for a number of records for oa_rejections using their open API:
https://developer.uspto.gov/ds-api-docs/index.html?url=https%3A//developer.uspto.gov/ds-api/swagger/docs/oa_rejections.json/v2#!/oa_rejections/perform_search

I have made the following php script. It ends up displaying just "Internal Server Error1":

```
<?
$params=['criteria'=>'*%3A*', 'start'=>'100', 'rows'=>'3']; 
$defaults = array( 
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://developer.uspto.gov/ds-api/oa_rejections/v2/records', 
CURLOPT_POST => true, 
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params, 
); 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt_array($ch, $defaults); 
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
echo $contents;
?>
```

Is there anything vital or obvious that I'm missing, or perhaps I cannot use this syntax at all to retrieve this data?

Comment: If I use https://developer.uspto.gov/ds-api/oa_rejections/v2/records?criteria=&#42;%3A&#42;&start=100&rows=3 I get a **Whitelabel Error Page**. So it is the URL that is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I see that too now. That's strange, because I visited that URL, or one similar that displayed json output.

Comment: You're welcome. Servers do sometimes have problems, your software should be able to cope with that. Assuming that API's will always work is a mistake.